# Incorrect date formats in Excel when importing or opening files

Tags: excel

I am noticing that many files that I use have incorrect date formats.  Specifically, some rows will contain correctly formatted dates (DateTime: MDY HH:MM:SS AM/PM), while others register incorrectly.  I know that others register incorrectly because although they look the same column cannot be sorted from newest to oldest, and shows that there are dates from the future in late 2014.  The typical column looks like this:

```
5/19/2014 10:39:24 AM
5/19/2014 10:39:24 AM
  07/02/2014 12:55:00 PM
  07/02/2014 12:55:00 PM
3/14/2014 8:25:49 PM
```

When I import the files to Excel I make sure to select MM/DD/YYYY format, and have tried again to format the problem cells with a custom format after having imported the file.  In both cases the dates still remain incorrectly formatted.  Would anyone happen to know what's causing this?

Note that these dates look the same in .csv as well:  One appears as

```
3/13/2014 12:48:06 PM
```

and is formatted in a 'custom' format MDY as specified in the import, while

```
3/31/2014 10:00:00 AM
```

comes up as 'general' format.

UPDATE/ANSWER:  This issue was resolved by changing regional settings in Windows.  Excel gets confused with mm/dd/yyyy formats if it is opening the file in a system where dd/mm/yyyy is standard.  When the 'month' is greater than 12 it gets confused and fails to format properly.

Comment: What kind of files are you importing and what are your local date settings? Seems like your system is looking for dd/mm/yyyy and so can't deal with (eg) `5/19/2014`

Comment: @Tim I imagine you're right regarding the local date settings.  Is there a way to change that?  I'm importing .csv files, though the same issue has occurred opening .csv files or even other .xls files.

Comment: One approach is to use `Data>>From Text` - if you step through the wizard you can specify incoming date formats explicitly

Comment: @Tim That was what I meant by importing.  Despite explicitly setting date columns to MDY the same issue occurs.

Comment: Can you show how the dates look in the source file, before importing to Excel?

Comment: @Tim That is how they look both in the .csv file and the .xls file, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: *exactly* like that? And I mean how do they look if you open the CSV file in something like notepad, not viewing it in Excel (which will helpfully "correct" things for you). Are some dates zero-padded and some not (`5` vs `07`) ?  If I put those values in a text file and import them - specifiying `MDY` for the date format - all is fine.

Comment: @Tim Exactly like that, unfortunately - without leading zeros.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce that behaviour in my version (Win7, XL2010)

Comment: @114 Just to be absolutely sure, when you are importing, are you doing this from the "Get External Data (from text)" tab on the Data Ribbon; or are you first "opening" the file, and then going to the Text to Columns wizard on the Data Tools tab of the Data Ribbon.  The latter won't work.

Comment: @114 And, when you look at the file in Notepad, are the "indents" that you show above also present?

Comment: @Ron The former, to be sure.  To your second point, the indents are slightly more pronounced in the .csv file because there will, on occasion, be multiple commas where blank spaces exist in one row, while there will be data in another.

Comment: @114 Is there any chance that there are some extra characters that is messing up the conversion.  In particular, a nbsp (ASCII code 160) will prevent the text wizard from properly processing the date; and it is not unusual to see in documents derived from an html source.

Comment: @Ron This might just be it, let me find a way to remove it if it exists.

Comment: @114 You can add that as an "other" character when you do the import.  Check the "other" box and then, with the cursor in the box next to it, while holding down the **alt** key, type **0160** on the numeric keypad.

Comment: @Ron That changed a number of dates (the ones that claimed to be custom formatted) to their number equivalents(e.g. 41976.8333333333) but I can't seem to get them back into date format.  The 'general' formatted dates remained the same.

Comment: @114 I'll post something as an Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that some of the dates include a **nbsp** character, which prevents the text import wizard from converting.

I would suggest the following.

The simplest might be to process the CSV file with a text editor and replace the nbsp's with nothing.

Other option might be

"Import" the .csv file
On the Text Import Wizard:

- Step 1 -- Delimited
- Step 2 -- select both the comma and, using the **Other** option, the **alt-0160** character
- Step 3 -- select DMY for any column that contains dates
- Clean up the extra cells if the process offsets some, but not all, of the data by one column.

Another option would be to convert the text number equivalents to real numbers.  You should then be able to format them.  This can be done by

- Enter a 1 in some blank cell
- Copy that cell
- Select the column of dates
- Paste/Special Multiply

You should then be able to format the cells as you wish.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Unfortunately the above options did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the CSV file that demonstrates the problem on some public site such as DropBox, OneDrive (or others) and post a link here so I might look at the data?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sqldeveloper importing the data from excel file it will show you map the source and target table columns, in this screen while mapping the date column select the format is empty one, then it automatically takes the format mentioned in the excel columns to table